# Windows 8.1 Spanish Latin American Keyboard Layout, lowercase enye

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am trying to type in a lowercase Ñ and cannot do it, I DO NOT want to use alt codes, i DO NOT want to edit the layout of a keyboard.

The keyboard I am using is: Spanish (United States) Latin American Keyboard.

I have it set up so I can easily switch between different keyboards (I have english, spanish, greek, hebrew) by pressing "win"+"space".  Never had this problem on XP or Win7. I can very easily type in an uppercase enye Ñ by pressing "shift"+";" but cannot find out how to type lowercase for the life of me.  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have a us keyboard (that is, a physical keyboard), in windows you select the 'Us International' and you can type the ñ, as SHIFT + ~ and then n.

Answer (score 0):

I have two keyboards installed in Windows 8.1, and one physical keyboard.  I have it set up so that I can alternate between the keyboards by striking ALT+SHIFT on the left side.

The physical keyboard came with the computer,  and it's the standard US keyboard.  One of the software keyboards is US standard as well.  The other keyboard is Spanish.  I don't remember which nationality it is.

When I want to type anything like this:  ñáéíóúü ¿¡

I usually switch to the Spanish keyboard.  I need a cheat sheet to tell me where the keys are, because they aren't painted on my keyboard, and I'm not a touch typist.

It's not hard to set things up this way, using standard Windows setup tools.  But I don't remember how I did it.

Comment: Yea, I have the keyboards set up for eng, spanish, greek, and hebrew, and can switch between them, In win7 i had no trouble typing in an ñ ...but now the best way I've figured out to do it is to press CapsLock and then capital Ñ (which for me is Shift + ; )

Comment: I did just now figure out a way to do it, not as simple as Win7 but if I (in spanish keyboard) press: ";" then Shift+";" then "n" it will do it. Not sure which one is more "convenient" seems like its a bug because the uppercase Ñ is very easy to type while the ñ either needs to have capslock turned for the above method.

Comment: Have you tried installing a Mexican Spanish keyboard instead of the one you have?  The semicolon key works just fine for a lower case enye, and shift or caps lock plus semicolon works just fine for an upper case enye.

Comment: @WalterMitty Got a link to a cheat sheet?

Comment: I don't have one handy... I'll see if I can dig one up.  Maybe on an old computer.